# LAContext and iOS7

Tags: ios7, touch-id

Will this code:

```
[LAContext class]
```

crash or return nil on a device that has the Touch ID sensor but is not running iOS8. (iPhone 5s is one such device.)

I'm trying to find such a device to test on but can't find one!

Note, that returns nil in the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not crash under iOS7. (Phew...)